# How to loop a function with an each loop inside and not crash the browser (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I am trying to iterate through a series of divs in a loop, altering the divs with each iteration at an even interval so as to *not* crash the browser.

In other words I am trying to have each div constantly shifting its shape and color. This is working 'sort of' but it seems to accelerate towards crashing.

```
 $(document).ready(function rainbow() {
   var newColor = '#' + (0x1000000 + (Math.random()) * 0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1, 6);
   var borderRadius = ((Math.random() * 100)).toFixed();
   $("html").click(function () {
     $(".main").children().each(function (index) {
       $(this).delay(100 * index).queue(function () {
         $(this).css({
           'background': newColor,
           'border-radius': borderRadius + '%'
         }).dequeue();
       });
     });
   });
   $(".main").children().each(function (index) {
     $(this).delay(100 * index);
     rainbow();
   });
 });
```

Comment: You should probably increase the delay time

Comment: And where is the `rainbow()`, what it does?

Comment: I tried playing around with the delay times but it didn't produce the desired effect and still inevitably overloads the browser. rainbow() is the name of the function. It is first named and then called.

Comment: how many are the children of `.main`?

Comment: Is your goal to build the ugliest, slowest and most annoying web page in the universe?